# Existence Of a Specific Header in Standard Library

Tags: c++, stl, std

So I was confused after reading different info from these sources: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header and https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=reference-standard-c-library-header-files

I'm writing this because I'm curious if **header filesystem** is part of standard library or not? Currently working with C++17

In the second link I couldn't find filesystem listed, while 'cppreference' states that it is part of standard library (from cpp17).

Comment: what "different info" do you refer to?

Comment: From the 1st link `<filesystem> (C++17)` so it depends on the version of the C++ Standard you are using.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm using C++17

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In the second link I couldn't find filesystem listed, while cppreference states that it is part of standard library (from cpp17).

Comment: you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74097074/edit) the question to clarify that. Don't let the reader rediscover what you already know.

Comment: The ibm docs talk about TR1 that were library extensions after C++03 and were incorporated into library after C++11 so it can not be about C++17. The filesystem was part of TR2 before C++17 <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1>

Comment: On the IBM site I can't find documentation to say what version of C++ is supported by their compiler.

Comment: Are you experiencing problems when you include <filesystem> ? Because if you are using a C++17 compatible compiler it should work (provided you tell it to compile the sources as C++17)

Comment: It looks like `IBM XLC++` does not  support C++17 see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/17 `C++17 core language features`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Nice regards

Comment: @fm_ Note that if you search "ibm C++ clang" it looks like IBM is no longer developing XLC and is now shipping/supporting clang.